# Loop through async requests with nested async requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have a scenario where I am calling an API that has pagination.
What I'd like to do is the following, 1 page at a time.

1. Call API Page 1
2. For each of the items in the response, call a Promise to get more data and store in an array
3. Send the array to an API
4. Repeat until all pages  are complete

What I currently have is the following, however I think I am possibly complicating this too much, although unsure on how to proceed.

```
export const importData = async() {
    const pSize = 15;
    const response = await getItems(pSize, 1);
    const noPage = Math.ceil(response.totalMerchandiseCount/pSize);

    for (let i = 1; i < noPage; i++) {
        const items = [];
        const data = await getItems(pSize, i);

        await async.each(data.merchandiseList, async(i, cb) => {
            const imageURL = await getImageURL(i.id, i.type);
            items.push({
                id: i.id,
                imageURL: imageURL,
            });
            cb();
        }, async() => {
            return await api.mockable('sync', items);
        });
    }
}

export const getImageURL = async(id, type) => {
    let url = `https://example.com/${id}`;

    return axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

            // do stuff to get imageUrl

            return image;
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
            return null;
        })
};
```

The issue I have at the moment is that it seems to wait until all pages are complete before calling api.mockable.  Items is also empty at this point.

Can anyone suggest a way to make this a bit neater and help me get it working?

Comment: Do you want to do the pages one after another, or in parallel?

Comment: Side note - This probably goes one fewer than you wanted: `for (let i = 1; i < noPage; i++) {`. Typically it's "start at 0 and use <" or "start at 1 and use <=".

Comment: You're using `async` as an identifier in some places (`async.each`, for instance). Is that from Axios? Or something else?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The pages should be on after another.  Get the first page, get the extra data, send the data, wait for response, next page.  async.each is from the async library, although again not sure I need it or if its complicating things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all meant to be serial, then you can just use a `for-of` loop:

```
export const importData = async() {
    const pSize = 15;
    const response = await getItems(pSize, 1);
    const noPage = Math.ceil(response.totalMerchandiseCount/pSize);

    for (let i = 1; i < noPage; i++) { // Are you sure this shouldn't be <=?
        const items = [];
        const data = await getItems(pSize, i);

        for (const {id, type} of data.merchandiseList) {
            const imageURL = await getImageURL(id, type);
            items.push({id, imageURL});
        }
        await api.mockable('sync', items);
    }
}
```

I also threw some destructuring and shorthand properties in there. :-)

If it's just the pages in serial but you can get the items in parallel, you can replace the `for-of` with `map` and `Promise.all` on the items:

```
export const importData = async() {
    const pSize = 15;
    const response = await getItems(pSize, 1);
    const noPage = Math.ceil(response.totalMerchandiseCount/pSize);

    for (let i = 1; i < noPage; i++) { // Are you sure this shouldn't be <=?
        const data = await getItems(pSize, i);
        const items = await Promise.all(data.merchandiseList.map(async ({id, type}) => {
            const imageURL = await getImageURL(id, type);
            return {id, imageURL};
        }));
        await api.mockable('sync', items);
    }
}
```

That `async` function call to `map` can be *slightly* more efficient as a non-`async` function:

```
export const importData = async() {
    const pSize = 15;
    const response = await getItems(pSize, 1);
    const noPage = Math.ceil(response.totalMerchandiseCount/pSize);

    for (let i = 1; i < noPage; i++) {
        const data = await getItems(pSize, i);
        const items = await Promise.all(data.merchandiseList.map(({id, type}) =>
            getImageURL(id, type).then(imageURL => ({id, imageURL}))
        ));
        await api.mockable('sync', items);
    }
}
```

Comment: (If you see `i.id` and `i.type` in the last code block -- or any of them, really -- hit refresh. Editing error.)

Comment: Perfect, pages in serial and items in parallel worked.  Thanks :)